# Proof expectation of bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have:

$P(X=k) =  (1-p)^k p$

$$E(X) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} kP(X=k)= \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} kp(1-p)^k = p(1-p) \frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{1-p}{p}$$

What I do not get is the step in the equation above:

$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} kp(1-p)^k = p(1-p) \frac{1}{p^2}$

How to get to the next step to show the expectation of the bernoulli distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Expected E (X) = 1$pq+2pq^2+3pq^3+4pq^4+\cdots$

E = $pq(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

S = $(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

qS = $q+2q^2+3q^3+....)$

S-qS = $1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots$

S(1-q) = $\frac{1}{(1-q)}$

S = $\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}$

E =$\frac{pq}{(1-q)^2}$

E = $\frac{1-p}{p}$

That will be your answer

This is a simple way to understand expectation.

Thanks

Satish

Answer (score 2):

The question has been answered, so we give a different derivation. If $p\ne 0$, our series clearly converges, so the expectation exists. Call it $a$.

On the first trial, either we have a success, in which case the expectation is $0$, or we have a failure. In that case, we have wasted a trial, and the expectation is $1+a$. It follows that
$$a=(1-p)(1+a).$$
Solve. We get $a=\frac{1-p}{p}$.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I got this intuitive approach! However, whats the mathematics behind the step I do not get? Why to differentialte?

Comment: Because it works! If you are interested in the sum $\sum ka_k x^{k-1}$, and you have a closed form for $\sum a_x^k$, say $f(x)$, then the sum you are interested in is $f'(x)$. If you are interested in $\sum \frac{a_k}{k+1}x^{k+1}$, you can similarly integrate $f(x)$. These are two important manipulations on *generating functions*. There are other ways to tackle your particular sum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** differentiate the equation: Sigma(k = 0 to infinity)(x^k) = 1/(1 - x) both sides,

then multiply both sides with x. Then let x = 1 - p.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Why to differentiate the equation. I do not get it and really would like to understand it on a deeper level.